# Shift certain values in a column of dataframe to a next column in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe that looks like the following:

```
x y z
1 2 3
1 2 3
1 2 3
2 3
1 2 3
1 3
```

I would like to ask if there is a command in R that will allow to obtain the following dataframe (by shifting and aligning similar values)

```
x y z
1 2 3
1 2 3
1 2 3
NA 2 3
1 2 3
1 NA 3
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @Ryan sorry Ryan for not clarifying. Well in simple words what I'm trying is to arrange the values so that to put all values which are equal to (1) in column x, values that are equal to (2) in column y and so on... so yes we could say it depends on first row and they must be equal

Comment: Okay, in that case my answer should work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  pmap_dfr(~{ x <- list(...)
              if(any(is.na(x))) intersect(x, df[1,]) # match with first row's values to assign names
              else x})
```

Output:

```
# # A tibble: 6 x 3
#       x     y     z
#   <int> <int> <int>
# 1     1     2     3
# 2     1     2     3
# 3     1     2     3
# 4    NA     2     3
# 5     1     2     3
# 6     1    NA     3
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative solution, where the main idea is to capture the pattern of your dataset based on rows that don't have NAs and then perform some reshaping using the pattern you captured.

```
df = read.table(text = "
x y z
1 2 3
1 2 3
1 2 3
2 3 NA
1 2 3
1 3 NA
", header= T)

library(tidyverse)

# get the column names of your dataset
names = names(df)

# get unique values after omitting rows with NAs
value = unlist(unique(na.omit(df)))

# create a dataset with names and values
# (this is the pattern you want to follow)
df3 = data.frame(names, value)


df %>%
  mutate(id = row_number()) %>%   # flag the row number
  gather(v,value,-id) %>%         # reshape
  na.omit() %>%                   # remove rows with NAs
  left_join(df3, by="value") %>%  # join info about your pattern
  select(-v) %>%                  # remove that column
  spread(names, value) %>%        # reshape
  select(-id)                     # remove row number

#    x  y z
# 1  1  2 3
# 2  1  2 3
# 3  1  2 3
# 4 NA  2 3
# 5  1  2 3
# 6  1 NA 3
```

Answer (score 0):

reading your data:

```
df<- fread("x y z
    1 2 3
    1 2 3
    1 2 3
    2 3 NA
    1 2 3
    1 3 NA") %>% setDF
```

code:

```
library(magrittr)
getmode <- function(v) {
    uniqv <- unique(v)
    uniqv[which.max(tabulate(match(v, uniqv)))]
}

pattern <- sapply(df,getmode)

df[!complete.cases(df),] %<>% apply(1,function(x){tmp<-pattern;tmp[!(tmp%in%x)] <- NA;return(tmp)}) %>% t %>% data.frame
```

result:

```
> df
   x  y z
1  1  2 3
2  1  2 3
3  1  2 3
4 NA  2 3
5  1  2 3
6  1 NA 3
```